# Реализация отзывчивого появления блока при наведении css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как называется фича когда реализовано отзывчивое появление блока при наведении (не выходит за границы главного контейнера). А еще лучше кинуть ссылку на реализацию данной фичи. То есть если глянем на рис 1, то облако выходит за границы контейнера, а и должно залезать внутрь как на рис 2-3.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сети полно плагинов. Гугли tooltip jquery

Хабр сделай сам https://habr.com/ru/post/42997/

Вот подборка https://www.appcues.com/blog/73-tooltip-plugins-made-with-jquery-css-javascript-or-more